# Reading messages offset in Apache Kafka

Tags: java, offset, apache-kafka, consumer

I am very much new to `Kafka` and we are using `Kafka 0.8.1`.

What I need to do is to consume a message from topic. For that, I will have to write one consumer in Java which will consume a message from topic and then save that message to database. After a message is saved, some acknowledgement will be sent to Java consumer. If acknowledgement is true, then next message should be consumed from the topic. If acknowldgement is false(which means due to some error message,read from the topic, couldn't be saved into the database), then again that message should be read.

I think I need to use  `Simple Consumer`,to have control over message offset and have gone through the Simple Consumer example as given in this link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example.

In this example, offset is evaluated in run method as '`readOffset`'. Do I need to play with that? For e.g. I can use `LatestTime()` instead of `EarliestTime()` and in case of false, I will reset the offset to the one before using `offset - 1`.

Is this how I should proceed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can get along with using the high level consumer (http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#highlevelconsumerapi), that should be easier to use than the SimpleConsumer. I don't think the consumer needs to reread messages from Kafka on database failure, as the consumer already has those messages and can resend them to the DB or do anything else it sees fit.

High-level consumers store the last offset read from a specific partition in Zookeeper (based on the consumer group name), so that when a consumer process dies and is later restarted (potentially on an other host), it can continue processing messages where it left off. It's possible to autosave this offset to Zookeeper periodically (see the consumer properties auto.commit.enable and auto.commit.interval.ms), or have it saved by application logic by calling `ConsumerConnector.commitOffsets` . See also https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example .

I suggest you turn auto-commit off and commit your offsets yourselves once you received DB acknowledgement. Thus, you can make sure unprocessed messages are reread from Kafka in case of consumer failure and all messages commited to Kafka will eventually reach the DB at least once (but not 'exactly once').

Comment: In case of DB failure, java consumer program will fail and need to start again after resolving the issue. So, consumer will again have to read message from topic. Could you please elaborate your 2nd solution how to set auto commit off in java code and what does that mean?

Comment: I've expanded my answer a little bit.

Comment: That really helps, Thanks..just one doubt regarding your last statement "all messages committed to Kafka will eventually reach the DB at least once (but not 'exactly once')." Do you mean a same message can be committed to database more than once? If yes, how can it be possible?

Comment: If the consumer dies after sending the data to the DB but before committing the new offset, the last message will be processed again. For performance, you might want to do processing in batches, so then this applies to the whole batch.

Comment: But that should be a rare case..right?? Also, which is best to use? Simple or High level consumer for my problem described as post?

Comment: I think that's rare. I suggest using the high level consumer, since with the low level consumer you'd have to take care of a couple of things yourself (keep track of offsets, find leader broker and track leader changes).

Comment: Right..I was just thinking why to use any acknowledgement as on any exception, while dealing with database, would make the consumer program stop..right??

Comment: Right, but that's only slightly related to your original question. ;-)

Comment: @sandris- Right :-) Now, let's assume there are 5 topics. First, i thought i can start a Java program which will spawn 5 threads, one for each topic but the issue i find is that if an exception comes even for a single thread(topic), then i need to terminate the java process explicitly to resolve the issue(may be due to database related code) which will make all other threads come to halt. Isn't it better to have 5 java processes for each topic?

Comment: Hi @Anand I am also working on same kind of application. In my case I also need to list out all the messages from topic everytime user asks for it. So How did you implemented your solution to read the previous messages from kafka topic?

Comment: @Samra- I used Kafka Consumer High level API to implement it. After reading the message from the topic, I saved it to database and only after successful insertion, I commit the offset and then next offset message will be read.However, if while insertion, any exception comes, offset will not be committed and the thread terminates.On subsequent consumer starts, again the same message will be read and the same process follows. I hope it helps you!!.

Comment: Thanks @Anand. That's really helpful. I have one more query. Is it possible to have fixed thread pool (say 5 threads) to consume messages from topics around 100 or more